# No taskbar, tty incorrect login

Tags: unity, password, system, tty

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04.

I've just installed `libfolks25` and it had to restart a few services to complete installation. Once it restarted and rebooted the system, the taskbar and Unity sidebar have now disappeared.

Tried going to `tty1` console however it won't let me login neither as my user nor as root.

I then logged in to the Gnome interface to get a terminal, as `ctrl+alt+t` doesn't work for some reason, and my sudo password no longer works so I can't access `aptitude` either to maybe remove `libfolks25`